# TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to read the value of something that triggered the event, in my case its Select tag but when I change the tag its giving me an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined`. I think it means event or target in undefined, My code is like this

```
function RandomScreen() {
  
  function handleChange(event) {
   ChangeSomeOtherState(event.target.value)
}

  return (
    <select onChange={() => handleChange()}>
            {StateWhichIsArray.map(String => {
                return (
                <option value={String} key={String} >{String}</option>
                )
            })}
        </select>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing any value to callback function , can do it like this

```
  <select onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}>
```

Or

```
  <select onChange={handleChange}>
```

You can refer to this codesandbox to do it right way

[image: Edit misty-forest-3gio1]

Comment: You don't need to call with expression, it will automatically have the calling event

Comment: In this question he did a callback , in that scenario he needs to pass , your example is also correct

Answer (score 2):

Remove `expression` to make the function get called with the calling event

```
<element onChange={eventHandler}>
```

Use `expression callback` when you want to pass any data to handler, Note this, when you do this way, you are creating a `fn` each time event get triggered which get heavy when you attach this to events like `scroll` or `keypress` or `drag` so be cautious when you do this

```
<element onChange={(yourData) => eventHandler(yourData)}>
```

So In your case it will look like this

```
return (
    <select onChange={handleChange}>
            {StateWhichIsArray.map(String => {
                return (
                <option value={String} key={String} >{String}</option>
                )
            })}
        </select>
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was answered by Gouthman ans Satyam, but i will try to explain what happened there with more details because I've seen  that is a recurrent error in a lot of developers.

1. The select selector executes the arrow function that you define implicitly.
2. The arrow function is who can take the event parameter but you are ignoring it and you are executing the `handleChange` function without pass the event object
3. the handleChange function throws error because does not recognize the event object.
4. **Important thing:** you are using an arrow function that calls another function passing the same value that gets by itself. It is redundant an unnnecessary, you could pass directly the `handleChange` function and make your code more concise and clear.